# showing average in new column of gridview

Tags: vb.net, gridview, webforms

I have a gridview, I am binding the gridview with a datatable. There are values in the rows of these dynamically generated columns. I need to calculate the average of each of these columns and display it in the column average. so far ive only found ways to display average calculation in footer.

| A | b | c | average |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 13 | 16 | 13 |
| 11 | 14 | 12 | 12.3 |
| 12 | 15 | 11 | 12. |

I am very new in vb.net. Please let me know how can I do this. if give reference website also accepted, because i really not find anything that i can refer.

Thanks.

here example code if do in footer.

```
Protected Sub GridView1_DataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles GridView1.DataBound
        Dim i, j, sum As Integer
        For i = 0 To GridView1.Columns.Count - 1
            For j = 0 To GridView1.Rows.Count - 1
                sum += Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.Rows(j).Cells(i).Text)
            Next
            GridView1.FooterRow.Cells(i).Text = Math.Round((sum / j), 2).ToString()
            sum = 0
        Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: How you do blid your grid with your data? Are you using a query? Or directly from the table?

Comment: Rather than setting the average value to the footer row, simply set the value of the column? Something like this: `GridView1.Columns("average").Rows(j).Value = Math.Round((sum / j), 2)`

Comment: Bear in mind you need to make sure you aren't including the average column in your loop, which you are currently doing with `For i = 0 To GridView1.Columns.Count - 1`. so I'd change to `For i = 0 To GridView1.Columns.Count - 2` to exclude the last column.

Comment: A `GridView` and a `DataGridView` are two different things. The question indicates the former while the tags indicate the latter. You should have also used a tag for Web Forms (`GridView` is a Web Forms control) or Windows Forms (`DataGridView` is a WinForms control). Using correct and consistent terminology is important because otherwise you breed confusion and confusion leads to someone - possibly everyone - wasting their time.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this.

```vb
For i = 0 To GridView1.Rows.Count - 1
    Dim sum As Integer
    For j = 0 To GridView1.Columns.Count - 2 '-2 to exclude last column
        sum += Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value)
    Next
    GridView1.Columns("average").Cells(i).Value = sum / (GridView1.Columns.Count - 1) ' divide sum by however many columns existed except the average one
Next
```

Comment: thanks. But what if my data is located not from first column. How do I call to get data value. where should I add the line

Comment: Then loop through the rows and only call `GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(XYZ).Value` on whatever columns you want to get the value, where `XYZ` is a column you want to include. If you need more help than that, you'll need to make your question clearer.